# Best way to schedule a background task for iOS?

Tags: ios

I have an app right now that allows a user to pull information from a website.  I unfortunately don't have any access to an API for the site, it's just something I screen scrape.  Ideally the user will scrape the information once a day from the site.
Currently I set a time and use `performFetchWithCompletionHandler`.  When `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` gets called, it checks the time that was set and if the time is the current time, it will perform the scraping.  Unfortunately, `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` doesn't work this way (I can't guarantee it will fire during the hour & minute that the user specified).  Is there a way to let my app run in the background and scrape a website at a designated interval?

Comment: Execute a `GCD block-based` operation using `NSTimer`.

Comment: @rmaddy, it's almost a duplicate, but that question was before fetch was around and fetch allows this to work, just not in the most ideal way.  I was hoping that something would have surfaced.

Comment: @SanjeetSuhag wouldn't the NSTimer get disabled when my app hits the background?

Comment: @TheRedAgent If you continue the same in you AppDelegate's methods then it won't.

Answer (score 1):

this may be helpful to you...

First declare ,
             NSTimer *timerAppBG;
in your AppDelegate.h file....

-> Please put bellow all methods in AppDelegate.m File...

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     timerAppBG = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60.0f target:self selector:@selector(applicationWillResign) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (void) applicationWillResign
{
      NSLog(@"About to lose focus");
     //Write your code here...
     [self myVcInitMethod];
}

- (void) myVcInitMethod 
{
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(applicationWillResign)
     name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
     object:NULL];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I added this in, but applicationWillResign never gets fired.  I put an NSLog just above the timerAppBg = [NSTimer...] and that gets fired, but for some reason the applicationWillResign never gets called (I don't see the "About to lose focus" line get called.